# Can we access data from Manifest.json in qooxdoo Application (ie. version number)?

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm developing libraries and end-user software using the

> qooxdoo framework

for 7 years now. I wonder if we can store version number in one place in `Manifest.json` and get it from the application to display it to users. As we use short development cycles and demo/test and serve our apps on different servers we rely extensively on version numbers to talk to users.

My question is : can we access data from `Manifest.json` in the application and particularly the `info.version`?

We currently use the generator from the

> 5.0.2 framework

and are migrating to

> qxcompiler

and

> 6.0.0-alpha

framework.

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying different keys with the `qx.core.Environment` object and further looking into generated code I found that all I need was under the `qx.libraryInfoMap` key. This environment value contains basically all the data from all `Manifest.json` of included libraries (including the qooxdoo framework itself). Each map key is a library name and each value the respective `Manifest.json` map.

For instance, accessing the version number of the project (library) `myProj` can be done like that:

```
var lim = qx.core.Environment.get('qx.libraryInfoMap'); // get the map
var ver = lim['myProj']['version']; // get the 'version' of the library 'myProj'
```