# Getting version info from Manifest file

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm using QX 5.0.2.

Is there a way to retrieve, for example, version information from the project Manifest file ?

I tried many env keys but I still not have found the right one. 
(maybe it's not that way to get it?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access version like any other info of Manifest.json like this:

```
var lim = qx.core.Environment.get('qx.libraryInfoMap'); // get the map
var ver = lim['myProj']['version']; // get the 'version' of the library 'myProj'
```

See [my question and response here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54421547/10978200)